# What is the derivative of this form?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider $\beta = z(y^2-x^2)\,dx\,dy - x^2y\,dx\,dz - xy^2\,dy\,dz$ to be a two-form on three dimensional real space. My question is, what is $d\beta$?

**Edit.** Henry Lee wrote in his answer the following.

> for a function defined in this form i.e. $\beta=f(x,y,z)$ you can say that:
>   $$d\beta=\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial z}dz$$

I know this, my question is, does $d\beta$ simplify to something nice in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, you should use the symbol $\wedge$, as this $\beta$ is not a symmetric tensor. Then ${\rm d}\beta$ will be a $3$-form. As a general fact (which you can check as an easy exercise), if we identify $$ \alpha = F_1\,{\rm d}y\wedge {\rm d}z + F_2\,{\rm d}z \wedge {\rm d}x + F_3\,{\rm d}x \wedge {\rm d}y \longleftrightarrow F = (F_1,F_2,F_3),$$then ${\rm d}\alpha = {\rm div}(F)\,{\rm d}x\wedge {\rm d}y \wedge {\rm d}z$. If you still do not have intuition about differential forms, your question amounts to asking whether the vector field $$F(x,y,z) = (-xy^2,x^2y,z(y^2-x^2))$$has nice properties. Since $${\rm div}(F) = -y^2 + x^2 + y^2-x^2 = 0,$$we have that ${\rm d}\beta = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

for a function defined in this form i.e. $\beta=f(x,y,z)$ you can say that:
$$d\beta=\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial z}dz$$

Comment: OP's $\beta$ is a $2$-form, not a $0$-form.